# Ruby array from two different sized arrays?

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash, dictionary, element

I have two Ruby arrays of `days` and `trips`, and the days of week as indicated below:

```
days = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"]
```

And the bus time schedule here:

```
trips = [
  "2.35pm","4.50pm","7.00pm",
  "2.35pm","4.50pm","7.00pm",
  "2.35pm","4.50pm","7.00pm",
  "2.35pm","4.50pm","7.00pm",
  "2.35pm","4.50pm","7.00pm",
  "2.35pm","4.50pm","7.00pm",
  "2.35pm","4.50pm","7.00pm"
]
```

The result am trying to achieve is this:

```
Bus-times = [
  "Monday","2.35pm","4.50pm","7.00pm",
  "Tuesday","2.35pm","4.50pm","7.00pm",
  "Wednesday","2.35pm","4.50pm","7.00pm",
  "Thusday","2.35pm","4.50pm","7.00pm",
  "Friday","2.35pm","4.50pm","7.00pm",
  "Saturday","2.35pm","4.50pm","7.00pm",
  "Sunday""2.35pm","4.50pm","7.00pm"
]
```

I've looked at interleaving, and `zip` only returns the first result if i don't write my own function. What other options do I have?

Comment: Your `trips` is invalid. Please post code that actually makes sense.

Comment: the trips array has been corrected, thank you for observing.

Comment: `Bus-times` will not work as a variable name. Ruby will think you're subtracting a variable named `times` from a constant or a class named `Bus`. In any case, your code will explode at that point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
bus_times = days.zip(trips.each_slice(3)).flatten
```

or if you want to keep them as an array of arrays:

```
bus_times = days.zip(trips.each_slice(3)).map(&:flatten)
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the code :

```
trips.each_slice(3).flat_map.with_index(0){|a,i| a.unshift(days[i])}
```

or,

```
[days,trips.each_slice(3).to_a ].transpose.flatten
```

**output**

```
[
    "Monday",
    "2.35pm",
    "4.50pm",
    "7.00pm",
    "Tuesday",
    "2.35pm",
    "4.50pm",
    "7.00pm",
    "Wednesday",
    "2.35pm",
    "4.50pm",
    "7.00pm",
    "Thursday",
    "2.35pm",
    "4.50pm",
    "7.00pm",
    "Friday",
    "2.35pm",
    "4.50pm",
    "7.00pm",
    "Saturday",
    "2.35pm",
    "4.50pm",
    "7.00pm",
    "Sunday",
    "2.35pm",
    "4.50pm",
    "7.00pm"
]
```

**Benchmark**

```
require 'benchmark'

days = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"]
trips= ["2.35pm","4.50pm","7.00pm","2.35pm","4.50pm","7.00pm","2.35pm","4.50pm","7.00pm","2.35pm","4.50pm","7.00pm","2.35pm","4.50pm","7.00pm","2.35pm","4.50pm","7.00pm","2.35pm","4.50pm","7.00pm"]


n = 50000
Benchmark.bm(7) do |x|
  x.report("ZIP")   { n.times{days.zip(trips.each_slice(3)).flatten} }
  x.report("MAP") { n.times{trips.each_slice(3).flat_map.with_index(0){|a,i| a.unshift(days[i])}} }
  x.report("TRANSPOSE")  { n.times{[days,trips.each_slice(3).to_a ].transpose.flatten} }
end
```

**Result**

```
              user     system      total        real
ZIP        0.800000   0.000000   0.800000 (  0.798833)
MAP        0.600000   0.000000   0.600000 (  0.597299)
TRANSPOSE  0.820000   0.000000   0.820000 (  0.826408)
```

Comment: Thank you hirolua and Arup Rashit for the answers. They all worked and have been very useful.